# Ruby on Rails Custom Rails Resource Routing Error Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I would like to route all broken site links for a rails resource to a particular custom error page and all other broken links to another custom error page.
For example:

/locations/wrong-location - Invalid location error page

/products/wrong-product - Invalid product error page

Does anyone know how to do this in Rails 3.2?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a catch-all in your `routes.rb`:

```
match 'locations/*other', to: 'locations#wrong-location'
```

or in Rails 4

```
match 'locations/*other', to: 'locations#wrong-location`, via: :all
```

And then just set up the controller and view.